# open atrium - securely share videos

Tags: distributions

Just started learning a more about open atrium.

Is there a way to securely share streaming videos on open atrium?

If so would this involve utilizing a contrib module?

Comment: Where are you videos coming form?

Comment: a private server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place any videos or other protected content on a Content Type that only certain roles have access. Then your users have to login to gain access, and only those with the appropriate role(s) get to see these pages with videos (or other protected content) on them.

You can use Ubercart(d6) or Commerce(d7) to create a product that is selling a role assignment to view your video (protected content) Content Type. Or a fairly simple custom module could track 'purchases' of specific media, granting access to only those pages hosting the purchased media.

For the media hosting & playback, the MediaFront module is a great free and open source media solution. And it plays nice with CDNs, when you get serious...

Answer (score 1):

If your videos come with some kind of embed code e.g. Youtube of Vimeo then you could embed them into Notebook pages in OA. This would make them visible only to the select users in that group.